# Most elegant way to start several scotty servers in the same application?

Tags: haskell, scotty

Is there a standard way to start two scotty servers in the same application? In a toy project I'm trying:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/" $ do
      text "hello"
  scotty 4000 $ do
    post "/" $ do
      text "world"
```

The first server spins up but the second one does not. It could also be a flaw in the way I'm understanding Haskell IO. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scotty` procedure does not return, it takes over control and continually serves requests to the webroutes.  If it did return then you'd have an issue with control flow - how would you keep the port open for when a request arrived?

One solution is to put each call to `scotty` in a separate thread.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
     build-depends: base, scotty
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Web.Scotty

main :: IO ()
main = do
  forkIO $ scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/" $ do
      text "hello"
  scotty 4000 $ do
    post "/" $ do
      text "world"
```

With operation of:

```
% curl -XPOST localhost:4000
world%
% curl -XGET localhost:3000
hello%
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async):

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a1 <- async $ scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/" $ do
      text "hello"
  a2 <- async $ scotty 4000 $ do
    post "/" $ do
      text "world"
  waitAnyCatchCancel [a1, a2]
```